# Enforce transactions for write operations in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactions, finance

How do I ensure and enforce that all write operations to my MS SQL Server DB are transactions-based?

The reason I want to do this is that the DB contains financial account data and operations that fail halfway through some set of changes should not be able to mess up the database by mistake or by crashing.

The application is written in ASP.NET C#.

Thanks.

Edit:
There is a DAL but it does not (yet) require transactions for changes.
We wrote the DAL ourselves. We did not use ORM.

I know how to perform one transaction from ASP.NET.

I want to ensure that **all** changes are made in transaction form so that if the application throws some exception in the middle, there will be no change to the database.

Comment: Do you use stored procedures and how are you accessing the database from your C# currently (e.g, is there a DAL layer? Is it one you wrote yourself or generated from some kind of ORM?) ?  There are a number of solutions to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at setting SQL Server to use implicit transactions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Any SQL-statement is atomic by default, but often you need to perform two or more of them and be sure the whole set is atomic. So you need to manually start and commit a transaction. If you use ADO.NET in your application the code can look like this:

```
using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
      db.Open();
      SqlTransaction transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
      try 
      {
         new SqlCommand("update statement", db, transaction).ExecuteNonQuery();
         new SqlCommand("another statement", db, transaction).ExecuteNonQuery();
         // additional operations here
         transaction.Commit();
      } 
      catch (SqlException sqlError) 
      {
         transaction.Rollback();
      }
}
```

Comment: +1, and one could maybe wrap up SqlCommand in to a custom Command object which throw an exception if a transaction was not in progress, otherwise simply forwarded the call on to the containing SqlCommand.

Answer (score 0):

All operations in MS SQL are transactions-based.  But trasactions can be [explicit and implicit](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/MS-SQL-Server/Scripts-and-Transactions-in-TransactSQL/2/).